# Make a program (aws cli) accessible for all users, installed by pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, aws-cli

i installed aws-cli using `sudo pip install awscli`
when i run awscli as current user it works but when i run try to run awscli as other user i get

```
sudo -u jenkins aws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
    import awscli.clidriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 28, in <module>
    import botocore.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore import waiter, xform_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 13, in <module>
    import jmespath
ImportError: No module named jmespath
```

Comment: That's most probably because JMESPath was not installed for all users. Run `pip show jmespath | grep Location` (as current user),  where does the location point to?

Comment: i ran it , it showsLocation: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages, how do install it for all users, when i run pip install it says jmes already installed.

Comment: Run `pip uninstall -y jmespath && sudo pip install jmespath`

Comment: Now its throwing error for a different module basically, i guess awscli is not properly installing, for other users.                                                  
ImportError: No module named docutils.core

Comment: `pip uninstall -y docutils && sudo pip install docutils` and so on until all dependencies are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue occured while I was using normal user.

```
# sudo -i    # switch to root
# aws configure          # give credencials
```

Then switch back to normal user. `aws configure` would be working for normal user and root user.